# Spread values over NAs

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` which I want to split into a list thereof.

I have:

```
data.frame(value=c(1:4,NA,11:12,NA,21:23,NA),
           key=as.factor(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"a",NA,NA,"b",NA,NA,NA,"c")))
   value  key
1      1 <NA>
2      2 <NA>
3      3 <NA>
4      4 <NA>
5     NA    a
6     11 <NA>
7     12 <NA>
8     NA    b
9     21 <NA>
10    22 <NA>
11    23 <NA>
12    NA    c
```

I want:

```
list(a=data.frame(value=1:4), 
     b=data.frame(value=11:12),
     c=data.frame(value=21:23))
$a
  value
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4

$b
  value
1    11
2    12

$c
  value
1    21
2    22
3    23
```

I should be able to use `split` to get what I want if I could convert the `key` column to

```
[1] a a a a a b b b c c c c
Levels: a b c
```

but, alas, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you your flat vector which you can `split` if you like:

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(f$key, fromLast = TRUE)

[1] a a a a a b b b c c c c
Levels: a b c
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
> f <- data.frame(value=c(1:4,NA,11:12,NA,21:23,NA),
                  key=as.factor(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"a",NA,NA,"b",NA,NA,NA,"c")))
> keys <- f$key
> good <- !is.na(keys)
> f$key <- NULL
> l <- split(f,head(cumsum(c(0,good)),-1))
> names(l) <- keys[good]
> lapply(l, function(df) head(df,-1))
$a
  value
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4

$b
  value
6    11
7    12

$c
   value
9     21
10    22
11    23
```

is there a better way?

Specifically, what I don't like is

1. the `head`+`cumsum`+`c` combination is ugly
2. the `lapply`+`head` combination is ugly

Answer (score 1):

This is also quite dirty, but if you don't mind ugly loops it works

```
> dat <- data.frame(value=c(1:4,NA,11:12,NA,21:23,NA),key=as.factor(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"a",NA,NA,"b",NA,NA,NA,"c")))
> 
> labels <- which(!is.na(dat$key))
> j <- 1
> for(i in labels){
+   dat$key[j:i] <- dat$key[i]
+   j = i + 1
+ }
> 
> split(dat$value[!is.na(dat$value)],as.factor(dat$key[-labels]))
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4

$b
[1] 11 12

$c
[1] 21 22 23
```